how to use vpngate softether app as proxy?
Buying a proxy is quite challenging and expensive for me
I've found vpngate(public vpn) works flawlessly
however, I want the specific app to have different IP each.
what if I redirect vpngate a proxy inside a vmware and the apps outside the VM will connect to it, will it work?
I need advice on how to set it up properly is there any good proxy app or tool to achieve this? Here is the reference photo:

